# How I can use a barcode scanner and PHP/MySQL to run a database?

Tags: python, php, mysql, html5

I am currently trying the following with the help of a Raspberry Pi:

- Barcode scanner scans barcode (connected to the Raspberry Pi via USB
  Port) (via Python?)
- A hidden form is filled in
- The user only sees the website
- With PHP and MySQL the scanned object is registered and you can change its status

  => (Out of stock, in stock)

Can you help me and maybe give tips on how to do that? Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
rib4n

Comment: A bit broad for this site, and really not specific to the Pi.  I would search for tutorials covering the various topics to see if you can find something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A barcode scanner is just a USB device that emulate keyboard. There is a python package called `evadev` that allows you to read input events on Linux. You can install the package from [python-evdev](http://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#).